# Create autocomplete input Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I try to create a method that let the user to insert just value that exists in database, like an autocomplete.
Right now returns a list, but that list is not sorted, doesn't matter what I type the data from the list are the same.

```
<b-form-group label="Name" label-for="name-input">
    <b-form-input
        id="name-input"
        v-model="query"
        @keyup="autoComplete"
    ></b-form-input>
    <div v-if="results.length">
        <ul>
            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(result, index) in results" :key="index"  id="display-none" @click="suggestionClick(result.name)">
                    {{ result.name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</b-form-group>


autoComplete() {
    this.results = [];
    if (this.query.length > 2) {
        get("/datafromapi", {
            params: {
                q: this.query
            }
        }).then(response => {
            this.results = response.data.data;
        });
    }
},
suggestionClick(index) {
    this.query = index
    var element = document.getElementById("display-none");
    element.classList.add("display-none");
},
```

Comment: Not sure if you're interested in using a component framework but there are some great ones that remove all the leg work for you i.e Quasar: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#Filtering-and-autocomplete

Comment: Hm, looks nice, I will give a try. Thanks!

Comment: Check if the backend is sending correct values.

Comment: From back I get a list of users. I must create a method that filter in that list and returns only the correct value.

Comment: @webnoob , that component seems to heavy just for an autocomplete input.

Comment: It does a lot more than auto complete - just an option if you're doing other things as well as Quasar really is a top class framework and it saves re-inventing the wheel if you're using lots.